Are $\sin{x}$ degrees and $\sin{x}$ radians considered different functions?
As I understand, functions map elements of a set to another, so they should be indifferent to such a thing as units. If $\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ is defined to be 1 then it should always equal 1, no matter what your interpretation of that input might be. And yet, clearly, $\sin{\frac{\pi˚}{2}}$ does not equal 1. This distinction is clearly reflected in programming languages. In Matlab, for instance, you have sin and sind. Is there such a distinction in mathematics, or is it just not too big of an issue for anyone to bother defining two functions?

You do indeed need two functions, namely $\sin$ and a function to convert degrees to radians. You can define a version of $\sin$ that takes degrees as input as their composition, but I doubt many people would opt to do that.

I guess the (non-negative restricted) domain of sin is always [0, 2$2\pi$] instead of [0, 360] then? So when people do stuff like sin(30˚) = $frac{1}{2}$, it's not that they're changing the function's domain, it's just that they're implicitly converting the argument? I think that was the source of my confusion all along.

It sounds as if you're more or less happy, but "yes" they are different functions, and "no" there is not a widely-named mathematical function whose value at an arbitrary real number $x$ is $\sin\frac{\pi x}{180}$.

In math, it is almost always radians. In fact, we omit radians and treat $x\,\mathrm{rad}$ as a number $x$. So, $\sin(x)$ means $\sin(x\,\mathrm{rad})$. Degrees are rarely used and denoted using $^\circ$, and the simple relation $x^\circ=x\pi/180$ suffices. So,
$$\sin(x^\circ)=\sin\left(\frac{x\pi}{180}\right)$$
If you wish, you can define $\operatorname{sind}(x)=\sin(x^\circ)$, but it is pretty much pointless, and inconvenient.
Here is another advantage: with the radian convention, we have the following simple identity $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. (No one will want to write $e^{ix180/\pi}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$.)
Hope this helps. :)

I figured that, if no such definition exists, it's probably because mathematicians did not think it worthwhile to do so. But I do think it's strange, since analysis is all about making thing things precise and rid of ambiguity and this seems very ambiguos to me, although, of course, for practical purposes, we can all just agree to use radians as is the case in fact.

@cabutchei: Why do you think it is ambiguous? We can compute $\sin$ at any point, in degrees, radian, whatever, using the math version.

Well, because we are giving two distinct functions the exact same name. I mean, just forgetting to write the ˚ symbol is enough to make your math wrong. Besides, it makes the function somehow sensitive to a choice of unit, when it shouldn't be. But I don't know, maybe I'm just overthinking all this stuff.

@cabutchei: You are overthinking. What I mentioned in this answer: there is no units involved -- radians are accepted as the natural units. As I said, no one uses $^\circ$ anyway, so there is no scope of mistake. And anyway that does not matter so much, missing basically any symbol might make your math wrong (imagine accidentally missing $+$ in $a+b$ oops!). [Also see my edit.]

In the same way that "$%$" is effectively shorthand for "$,\times\frac{1}{100},$" (so that "$,x%,$" means $\frac{x}{100}$), I like to think of "$,^\circ,$" as shorthand for "$,\times\frac{\pi}{180},$" (so that "$,x^\circ,$" means $\frac{x\pi}{180}$).

@cabutchei Analysis is more about rigour, and correctly identifying sufficient conditions, than disambiguation. I understand your frustration, but it results from trigonometry being invented before radians, and long before calculus motivated working exclusively in radians (although some formulae in geometry already made that a very good idea).

@Blue interesting, I do like this way of seeing it

I'd like to thank you all, those were really enlightening answers. I'm at peace with this whole thing now
